# How would formally ask someone to confirm return date to book a ticket

Tags: questions, interrogatives

I would like to book a return ticket back to my hometown for a particular date. I need to ask my someone before finalizing the date. How can I express that in a question form? I have few examples:

> - (For) which date/day should I book my return ticket?
> - When should I return?
> - I am thinking of returning on xyz date. Is that okay?
> - Which date/day should I return (on)?

Similarly, is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> - I booked my return ticket for my hometown for xyz date.

Comment: This is a bit broad... your "someone" ... who might that be? Your boss, your wife, your travel agent, your dog?

Comment: @ Tetsujin Well, I would be happy to know for friend, parent, travel agent etc. But, my original 'someone' is my manager.

Comment: Then your question is really "When do you need me back here, at work?" & you figure out your needs from that, inc/exc weekends... Incidentally, you never book a return ticket 'to here', you book it to the other end of the line - it's assumed that the return portion is always going to be 'to here', hence the name, return. ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I believe that you mean that you book it *from* the other end of the line, yes?

Comment: No... from the old joke. "Can I have a return ticket please?" Sure, where to? "To here, of course."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"(For) which date/day should I book my return ticket?"**

This is a little formal and old-fashioned. Try "When am I starting work again?" or "What date should I come back to work?" That way you can book your return ticket for the day before.

**"I am thinking of returning on xyz date. Is that okay?"** **Which date/day should I return (on)?**

Yes these are fine. (Also, the last sentence is grammatically correct.)